# Issue concerning the Y parameter in tbl_uvregression function inside a function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, parameters, gtsummary

So I am trying to input the Y parameter of the tbl_uvregression function (gt_summary package) via a custom function. The idea is to create multiple tbl inside my function and return the different tables merged.

Here an example of the code I am using:

```
#Loading libraries + example dataset from questionr package

library(haven)
library(tidyverse)
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(glue)
library(gt)
library(knitr)
library(questionr)

data(hdv2003)
```

Here is the part where I have an issue :

```
reg_log <- function(dataframew, variables, by) {
  #@param1 : weighted dataframe
  #@param2 : vector containing variables we want in our graph
  #@param3 : the variable or column we want as our Y argument

  Table <- tbl_uvregression(data = dataframew, include = variables, exponentiate = TRUE, method.args = list(family = quasibinomial()), y = by, method = survey::svyglm)
  return(Table)
}
```

When I run this function outside of reg_log, I have no issue, but it seems that inside a function, the Y parameter of tbl_uvregression does not evaluate the argument, but instead read it literally. Here's the error I get when calling my function:

```
hdv2003w <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = hdv2003, weights = ~hdv2003$poids) #setting the survey.design object

reg_log(hdv2003w, c("age", "sexe", "hard.rock", "sport"), "sport")
```

> x There was an error constructing model `survey::svyglm(formula = by ~ age, design = ., family = quasibinomial())` See error below. Erreur : Problem with `mutate()` column `model`.
> i `model = map(...)`.
> x Error in svyglm.survey.design(formula = by ~ age, design = structure(list(: all variables must be in design= argument

I am aware that the Y parameter requires a syntax without the quotes, but even when I'm using the substitute() function it does not work. I have resolved myself to make several possibilities using the switch function, but if anyone knows how to resolve this, it will be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tbl_uvregression()` function expects an unquoted input for `y=`, rather than a string with the outcome name. I updated your function to account for the string input.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(questionr)
data(hdv2003)

reg_log <- function(dataframew, variables, by) {
  tbl_uvregression(
    data = dataframew, 
    include = all_of(variables), 
    exponentiate = TRUE, 
    method.args = list(family = quasibinomial()), 
    y = !!rlang::sym(by), 
    method = survey::svyglm
  )
}

hdv2003w <- survey::svydesign(ids = ~1, data = hdv2003, weights = ~hdv2003$poids) #setting the survey.design object

tbl <- 
  reg_log(hdv2003w, c("age", "sexe", "hard.rock"), "sport")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>